# ERROR 404 NOT FOUND URL AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo dos ajax que ejecutan dos archivos php, he intentado ordenar la carpeta y he puesto una de prueba donde he metido los archivos php y he cambiado la url de los ajax. Pero cada vez que ejecuto me salta un error o si no me salta el error no me ejecuta el script. He probado varias rutas desde ./ ../ solo el nombre del archivo y no deja no entiendo el porque. Pero si los archivos php los dejo fuera de la carpeta prueba y en la url solo pongo el nombre del archivo funciona correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en ajax lo pongo de esta forma:

```
  $.ajax({
        url: '/prueba/randomImatge.php',

  $.ajax({
        url: '/prueba/actualitzarLikesDislikes.php',
```

Y cuando lo saco fuera de la carpeta prueba y en url pongo solo el nombre del archivo si funciona, no entiendo el porque. Como podria indicar la ruta y que me lo detecte y ejecute sin problemas? He probado con ./prueba.... y nada

Comment: ¿En qué nivel de directorios está el archivo desde donde haces la petición? ¿En el directorio raíz del proyecto?

Comment: Exactamente, es un proyecto y prueba es la primera carpeta, el archivo ajax esta fuera de la carpeta

Comment: Intenta eliminando la primera diagonal: `url: 'prueba/randomImatge.php',`

Comment: He probado y tampoco. No entiendo a que se debería. Lo mismo me pasa si meto el archivo ajax en otra carpeta y intento llamar el php que esta en otra carpeta.

Comment: Pon una captura del árbol de directorios donde se pueda ver tanto el archivo donde está la petición Ajax así como los archivos de la carpeta `prueba`. Las explicaciones son confusas y no se entiende dónde está cada cosa.